# Sound not playing first time even if Libgdx says it's loaded into memory

Tags: java, android, audio, libgdx

I'm using Libgdx and AssetManager to load assets into memory. First I thought that something is wrong with my project so I made a new clean one, and the problem persists.

The Sound is not playing even if I use "IsLoaded" method and is not playing the first time (if you jump really quick into the game). The sound is small , like 40KB, and this happens only on Android (works on Desktop/iOS). The device I'm testing on Android is HTC One M7 with Lolipop. Here is the code of a clean project.

```
package com.mygdx.game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Audio;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ScreenAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;


public class MyGdxGame extends ScreenAdapter {

    private AssetManager assetManager;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();

        assetManager = new AssetManager();

            assetManager.load("sound/jump.mp3", Sound.class);

    }


    Sound jump;
    boolean isLoaded;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        super.render(delta);


        if(isLoaded) return;

        assetManager.update();

        if(assetManager.isLoaded("sound/jump.mp3", Sound.class)) {
            assetManager.finishLoading();
            jump = assetManager.get("sound/jump.mp3", Sound.class);
            isLoaded = true;
            System.err.println("LOADED");
            jump.play();

        }



        }
    }
```

In LOGCAT I'm getting "soundpool sample 1 not ready" error.
Any ideas?

NOTE: The sound is playing as normal if I give it a little time (If I don't press "play" right away).

The question is why does Libgdx thinks that the sound is loaded into memory even if its not.

Comment: does it work with several different audio files?

Comment: You mean if I tried with other sound assets? Yes I did, with two different sound assets (0.7-2seconds long) and the result is the same.

Comment: I believe this is bug in Ligdx. If I use "Music" file type, it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .ogg instead? 
On my libgdx projects i always used .ogg, since its license -free and well, it never gave me issues!

You should also be careful with the different Sound imports. I remember that you can sometimes import directly .ogg .mp3 classes from libgdx and that causes issues.

Also, i think the problem is that, even if the audio file was loaded, the assetmanager is still loading other resources.. so its busy doing another task.

I would either :

a) Play that sound without the assetmanager, since its just for the loading, right?

b) (This needs to be checked) But Maybe use a different assetmanager for that audio? Unsure how much resource would it waste by having 2 assetmanagers..

But, i would try that. Change to .ogg first, be sure the audio starts at exactly 0:00 and update to the last libgdx version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue. I am using libgdx version 1.9.2. So far, I tried:

- changing mp3 to ogg
- using different asset manager for sounds

and it didn't help.

I **replaced** Sound object with Music object and it did help. But I'm not sure if this is the right approach, because I have a lot of short sounds in my app.

Comment: It's not the right approach to replace Sound with Music. I temporarily solved my issue , that I give my sounds to AssetManager BEFORE textures. So sound is loaded into memory while textures are loading.

Comment: Did you test it on Android 6.0? When I finally managed to handle this issue on < 6.0 it turned out half of sounds doesn't work properly on Marshmallow..

Comment: No unfortunately I didn't test this on Marshmallow. I will try on emulator since I don't have a device with android 6.0.  I wonder why libgdx team won't fix this issue,since it's quite old.

Comment: Facing the same issue even on android 8 (Nexus 6P). Sound playing works well everywhere except at app start on android. Must be that issue is asynchronous loading of sound files, somebody mentioned. After app starts all other sounds are playing well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I just ran into this same problem and I solved it like this..

```
private Sound sound;
private float soundVolume;

public void playSound(String path, float volume) {
    sound = assetManager.get(path, Sound.class);
    soundVolume = volume;
}

@Override
public void render () {
    super.render();

    // Because of some weird Android bug
    if (sound != null) {
        sound.play(soundVolume);
        sound = null;
    }
}
```

This is in my main game class and I can call the `playSound()` method from any other class.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused by Gdx.audio.newSound() method is loading the sound by asynchronously instead asserting sound loading process to processor. I solved this by adding a "delay" to the playing sound process only for the first playing. That solved my problem.

```
private static void soundBugFixer(Sound sfx, float volume)
{
    Timer x = new Timer();
    x.scheduleTask(new Timer.Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sfx.play(volume);
        }
    }, 0.1f );
}

public static void remove(float volume) {
    if(sfxRemove == null)
    {
        sfxRemove = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sfx/sfx_remove.wav"));
        soundBugFixer(sfxRemove, volume);
    }
    else
    {
        sfxRemove.play(volume);
    }
}
```